# Java Security and javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source) javafx

Tags: java, security, netbeans, client-certificates, java-security

The problem is I cannot start my **JavaFX FXML Application** in WebBrowser. I use NetBeans 8.1 as IDE, Windows 8 64-bit and jdk1.8.0_65. So, if I create a new **JavaFX Application** - it works. It works as a desctop and it works when I start it inside the WebBrowser. But if I create new **JavaFX FXML Application** it won't work. It works as a desctop application perfectly, but when I tried to start ***.jnlp** or in WebBrowser I got this:

```
> Missing Application-Name manifest attribute for: file:/C:/Users/Sergey.Lotvin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication5/dist/JavaFXApplication5.jar
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at javafxapplication5.JavaFXApplication5.start(JavaFXApplication5.java:22)
```

What I did:

1. New Project > **JavaFX FXML Application**
2. Run to check if it works. So, button "Click Me" on the place, click and label "Hello World!" appeared.
3. Then go to project properties>Run>Run in Browser
4. Start Java Config and add **file:///C:/...** to exception list
5. I even signed my **JavaFX FXML Application** using

`keytool -genkey -keystore .keystore -alias «Terrasoft» -validity 99999` `jarsigner.exe -keystore .keystore myJavaFXFXMLApplication.jar «Terrasoft»` For sure I've created **.keystore** before etc. So I got message in **cmd** like - jar signed.

6. I got picture [image]
7. but then picture [image]

I've changed
    `Parent root =FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLMain.fxml"));`
in different way without success.

jar structure [image]

Questions:

1. How to force it to work?
2. Why do one need all this difficults with certifications?

Comment: Include the output of `jar tvf JavaFXApplication5.jar` on the jar file you are using. Is `/javafxapplication5/FXMLMain.fxml` inside the jar at exactly that position?

Comment: FXMLMain.fxml - in **JavaFXApplication5.jar** location is:  **C:\Users\Sergey.Lotvin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXApplication5\dist\JavaFXApplication5.jar\javafxapplication5\**

Comment: [`jar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) is a command line tool that ships with the jdk, you run it in a console window and it outputs the console window.  You can copy and paste the output from the command, and edit your question to include it.

Comment: yep. i've updated the question with jar structure